# Problemas em insert no Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Estou tentando inserir um usuário no banco de dados PostgreSQL no servidor web Heroku.

Os atributos do usuario no banco de dados PostgreSQL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem observar existe uma coluna chamada grupos, e toda vez que estou tentando submeter o fomulário ele salva todos os dados das outras colunas menos o **grupos**, eu fiz tudo certo na implementação e não sei o que está de errado.

Logo em seguida depois de submeter o formulário quando vou checar realizando um select na tabela fica o campo como null, porém eu coloquei um print no controller para saber se de fato está enviando os dados como no código abaixo;

System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + usuario.getGrupos());

O que acontece que é que esse componente na pagina HTML é realmente submetido como mostra o log abaixo;

```
2017-07-03T19:10:33.983122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/usuarios/novo" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com request_id=85833251-bd54-44a5-ae4e-fb78
fecd9da0 fwd="177.223.27.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=344ms status=302 bytes=427 protocol=https
2017-07-03T19:10:33.845939+00:00 app[web.1]: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[br.com.arm.model.Grupo@20]
2017-07-03T19:10:34.140090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/usuarios/novo" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com request_id=8131592c-831e-4d30-9e90-b16a8
6fba6a2 fwd="177.223.27.17" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=200 bytes=8974 protocol=https
2017-07-03T19:10:34.358827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/javascripts/vendors/jquery.maskMoney.min.js" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com request_id
=75c6c474-e484-4ee4-8dad-2be026665f70 fwd="177.223.27.17" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=5510 protocol=https
```

Essa é minha pagina controller

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/controller/UsuarioController.java

Essa é minha entidade usuário

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/model/Usuario.java

Essa é minha pagina Web

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/tree/master/arm/src/main/resources/templates/usuario

Alguém conseguir ver algo errado no meu projeto Spring Boot.

Se eu for inspecionar a pagina posso encontrar isso abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É estranho porque parece que está tudo certo!

se eu colocar no controller essa linha de código

```
System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + usuario.getGrupos().size());
```

E marcar o grupo administrador o resultado vai ser **1**,
Isso quer dizer que está certo.

então é tudo muito estranho.

O mais estranho ainda é que ao submeter o formulário usuário ele não inserir os dados na coluna grupos, porém ele inseri os dados na tabela usuario_grupo como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso somente poderia acontecer se a coluna grupos na tabela usuario fosse gravada, porém não grava os dados na coluna grupos, mas a tabela usuario_grupos são gravadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite até onde sei relacionamento ManyToMany cria uma terceira tabela com a chave no caso de usuário e grupo. Ou seja pelo q demonstrou não tem nada de errado. 
Quando recupera essa entidade ele traz a lista de grupos preenchida?